# How to make view model bindings work with custom Shell App Title View - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

### Context

I'm trying to make a customizable, re-usable Title View template for my Xamarin Forms Shell app. By "Title View", I mean the title bar that appears at the top of a page. **I've mostly implemented it, but I'm struggling to make some bindings work.**

The idea is pretty simple. I want to end up with something that looks like this, a pretty standard title bar template where I can fill in the blanks on a page-by-page basis:

[image]

And I want to be able to create it like this in any of my `ContentPages`. I've rigged it so that I only need to tell the buttons what their image source and commands are, and the rest will be formatted for me:

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:DataType="viewmodels:MyViewModel"
    ... >

    <Shell.TitleView>
        
        <tv:CustomAppShellTitleView>
                        
            <tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.LeftButton>
                <tv:TitleViewButtonInfo Command="{Binding SomeCommandHere}" Source="{StaticResource SomeIconHere}" />
            </tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.LeftButton>

            <tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.Title>SomeTitle</tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.Title>

            <tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.RightButton1>
                <tv:TitleViewButtonInfo Command="{Binding SomeCommandHere}" Source="{StaticResource SomeIconHere}" />
            </tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.RightButton1>

            <tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.RightButton2>
                <tv:TitleViewButtonInfo Command="{Binding SomeCommandHere}" Source="{StaticResource SomeIconHere}" />
            </tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.RightButton2>

            <tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.RightButton3>
                <tv:TitleViewButtonInfo Command="{Binding SomeCommandHere}" Source="{StaticResource SomeIconHere}" />
            </tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.RightButton3>
            
        </tv:CustomAppShellTitleView>
        
    </Shell.TitleView>
...
```

All of my `ContentPages` use view models, and I want to use data from them to configure the title bar behaviour (e.g., button commands, visibily, etc).

### TitleViewButtonInfo

You'll notice that I've used something called `TitleViewButtonInfo`. I figured that since I've got 4 possible buttons, I could reduce code duplication by putting their Bindable Properties in a nice little object, like so:

```cs
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace.Views.TitleViews
{
    public class TitleViewButtonInfo : BindableObject
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(TitleViewButtonInfo), default(ICommand));
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty SourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Source), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(TitleViewButtonInfo), default(ImageSource));
        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get => (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty);
            set
            {
                SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
            }
        }

        public bool IsVisible => Source != null;
    }
}
```

### CustomAppShellTitleView

And lastly, I've got my *actual* `CustomAppShellTitleView`. I'm going to omit the right-side buttons for simplicity:

#### XAML

```xml
<ContentView
    x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.TitleViews.CustomAppShellTitleView"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Views.TitleViews"
    x:Name="customAppShellTitleView"
    x:DataType="local:CustomAppShellTitleView">
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <x:Double x:Key="ButtonSize">32</x:Double>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid
            Padding="0,0,10,0"
            RowSpacing="0"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--  Left-side Button  -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <!--  Title  -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <!--  Right-side Buttons  -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--  Left-side Button  -->
            <ImageButton
                Grid.Column="0"
                Command="{Binding LeftButton.Command, Source={x:Reference Name=customAppShellTitleView}}"
                HeightRequest="{StaticResource ButtonSize}"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                IsVisible="{Binding LeftButton.IsVisible, Source={x:Reference Name=customAppShellTitleView}}"
                Source="{Binding LeftButton.Source, Source={x:Reference Name=customAppShellTitleView}}"
                WidthRequest="{StaticResource ButtonSize}" />

            <!--  Title  -->
            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                MaxLines="1"
                Text="{Binding Title, Source={x:Reference Name=customAppShellTitleView}}"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <!--  Right-side Buttons  -->
            <StackLayout
                Grid.Column="2"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Spacing="10">
                <!--  Buttons 1, 2 and 3 here -->
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

#### Code Behind

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyNamespace.Views.TitleViews
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomAppShellTitleView : ContentView
    {
        // LeftButton
        public static readonly BindableProperty LeftButtonProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(LeftButton),
            typeof(TitleViewButtonInfo),
            typeof(CustomAppShellTitleView),
            new TitleViewButtonInfo());

        public TitleViewButtonInfo LeftButton
        {
            get => (TitleViewButtonInfo)GetValue(LeftButtonProperty);
            set => SetValue(LeftButtonProperty, value);
        }

        // Same thing for RightButton1, 2 and 3

        #region Title Property
        public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(CustomAppShellTitleView), default(string));
        
        public string Title
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
        #endregion

        public CustomAppShellTitleView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

### The Problem

This setup seems to work for the most part. Everything looks nice. The title and button image sources are being set properly at runtime, mainly because they are static values that *exist* at the time the `Shell.TitleView` is set in my page's XAML. However, the **Bindings** are the issue. For instance, the buttons do nothing when they are pressed despite having their `Command` properties bound to some `ICommand` in my view model. This command works fine when I bind it to a regular button in my view, so it's not due to some mismatch between my XAML and view model.

There are clearly some fundamental things I don't understand here.

### What I've Tried

I set breakpoints in the `TitleViewButtonInfo.CommandProperty` and my view model's constructor where the commands are being assigned. Since the view is initialized prior to the view model being set as the BindingContext (or even existing), this makes sense -- but the setter for the `CommandProperty` is never hit again once the view model has actually set it. Obviously, the first time it hits, the value will be null since the view model hasn't initialized yet. Thus, even when that ICommand *is* set in my view model, the title view doesn't hear it. I tried to trigger an `OnPropertyChanged` on the Command that was bound, but that didn't work.

Is there any way to make it *hear* when the Command in my view model is set? There must be something obvious that I'm doing wrong to make it such that the properties of this title view can only be set *once* and never again.

Comment: *"the setter for the CommandProperty is never hit again once the view model has actually set it"* This isn't necessarily the cause of the problem. XAML binding propagation apparently can use BindableProperty's change handler, rather than calling the associated property's Set. If you add `propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue => { ... }` to a BindableProperty.Create, you can set a breakpoint to see what `newValue`s come in. [I say this based on observation of issues I've encountered, not an any doc statement. I've needed to move code from a setter to a property change handler. ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BindingContext for TitleViewButtonInfo is not the ViewModel for the page. So you may set the binding source for it. Consider the following code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         x:Name="this">

<Shell.TitleView>
    <tv:CustomAppShellTitleView>
        <tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.LeftButton>
            <tv:TitleViewButtonInfo Command="{Binding BindingContext.LeftButtonCommand,Source={x:Reference this}}" ... />
        </tv:CustomAppShellTitleView.LeftButton>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: This worked! The only suggestion I have for making this more clear to future readers is to maybe revise the explanation a bit -- but thank you!